# Webbrowser flicker issue

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, flicker

i have a windows form application with a web browser control , simple when i reload any page on the web browser control the header of my application flickers , it is so strange because i am using that code to reduce the flickering as much as possible :

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, false);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, false);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
    }




    int originalExStyle = -1;
    bool enableFormLevelDoubleBuffering = true;

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            if (originalExStyle == -1)
                originalExStyle = base.CreateParams.ExStyle;

            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            if (enableFormLevelDoubleBuffering)
                cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;   // WS_EX_COMPOSITED
            else
                cp.ExStyle = originalExStyle;

            return cp;
        }
    }
    private void TurnOffFormLevelDoubleBuffering()
    {
        enableFormLevelDoubleBuffering = false;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TurnOffFormLevelDoubleBuffering();
    }
```

** It flickers only when IE8 is installed , but if IE9 is installed then it does not flicker.

Comment: Perhaps it was a bug in the IE8 version of the webbrowser control?

Comment: Maybe i am just trying to figure out why it flickers

Comment: Does IE exhibit the same behavior?

Comment: I do not know , actually my client says that but i told him to visit facebook for example because he is using a localhost page

Comment: What does "header of my application" mean?  Does the form's Activated event fire repeatedly?

Comment: Any luck with my suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These suggestions are going off of the premise that the issue would manifest itself in IE as well.

Two things you could try:
 - Install the latest video drivers.
 - Try updating Adobe Flash. (You can start IE with No Addons to see if flash is the culprit.)

Answer (score 0):

"Instead of reloading a new document every time, set the InnerHTML of the existing Document.Body."